# boostrap different columns in cards?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

What I'm trying to do is to basically size the 180x180px avatar to make it fit:

[image]

I made the `<card-img-top>` have a column of `col-sm-2` and the card block itself `col-sm-6`. Now what happened is this:

[image]

Here is my code for the second one:

```
<div class="usercard">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div class="card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=htmlspecialchars($row['avatar']);?>" alt="Card image cap">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The <div class="col-sm-6"> is inside of the <div class="col-sm-2">.

Comment: @bert now it looks even more weird lol.

Comment: You need to wrap both of those divs (sm-2 and sm-6) inside div class row. <div class="row"><div class="col-sm-2"></div><div class="col-sm-6"></div></div>